# angular js directive sending an object as response and displaying only one value from that

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a directive as shown below:

```
module.directive("typeahead", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,controller) {
            console.log(element);
            var model = attrs.ngModel;
            var config = {
                key: 'mykey' ,
                faces:{
                    onclick: function(person) {
                        controller.$setViewValue(person);
                        controller.$render();
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            };
            TypeAhead.init(element,config);
        }
    };
});
```

I am calling this directive in my input field when the user starts typing something. The person object will be looking something like this:

```
{
    name:'my name',
    email:'myemail',
    sno:'myserialno'
}
```

I want the entire person object to be sent but in the input want to display only name. "serial no" and "email" are needed for my backend api calls but not needed for display. how can I achieve this as the above code is displaying `[object object]`.

This is my html code

Comment: It would be really helpfull if you can post html code also but i think `controller.$setViewValue(person);` should be `controller.$setViewValue(person.name);`

Comment: controller.$setViewValue(person.name) will give the name but I will loose serial no and email. my ultimate goal is for display purpose I need name and for my backend api call will be passing the email

Answer (score 0):

You can change your click function to do the following:

```
onclick: function(person) {
    // set only the name as the value
    controller.$setViewValue(person.name);

    // do your API calls or prepare for them here
    // scope.person = person;
    // OR
    // myAPICall(person);

    controller.$render();
    scope.$apply();
}
```